# Use local phpMyAdmin to connect to remote database through Xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, database-connection, remote-access

I'm a beginner so please bear with me.

I wish to access and work on client remote database server from localhost using phpMyAdmin Xampp. From what I search online, I know I need to change the code in file config.inc.php as shown below.

```
$i++;
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '';                       //server host name or IP
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';            
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';                       //Account username
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';                   //Account password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

But after I changed I got some error messages.

```
#1045 - Access denied for user (using password: YES) 

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I have gone through similar cases and found that I should create a new user in the database. But I got another errors after changed.

```
#1129 - Host is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' 

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem and was hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

What's interesting about this error combined with the config.inc.php you've posted is that the error message indicates a problem with the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']` directives -- which aren't set in the file you've posted. The controluser is an administrative user managed by phpMyAdmin to give you access to some advanced options; it's not required and I suggest skipping over it until you get your basic configuration working. I suggest using a tool (such as grep) to look for other mentions of the text 'controluser' to see if there might be another file used by xampp that's interfering with your config.inc.php.

phpMyAdmin certainly can connect to a remote MySQL instance, but most system administrators do not allow this (either by blocking incoming TCP requests at the firewall or directly from MySQL). I wonder if you're being affected by some similar protections.

> ## 1129 - Host is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

This means there have been too many errors when connecting; you need to run the command `mysqladmin flush-hosts` on the host (at the command/shell prompt; not the MySQL prompt) to clear things out.

Answer (score 0):

You should Add Access Host
go to your c-panel and click Remote MySql and add access host by providing your IP

Comment: I think that time I couldn't access to c-panel. So I can't do anything that need the setting from c-panel.